# Is it possible to search for a particular filename on GitHub?

Tags: github, search-engine

I know that the GitHub web interface lets you search all repositories for files with a particular pathname (e.g. searching for `path:/app/models/user.rb` yields > 109k results), but is there a way to search all repositories for filenames independent of their subdirectory location?  I tried using asterisks in the `path` argument, and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: IMO it is bad design that GitHub search doesn't default to including filenames in results. Atm, if you search a repo for the name of a file, and the name of the file doesn't appear in the body of a file (only as the name of the file), then the file won't be returned in the results.

Comment: Just use `path:**/user.rb`

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Does the [search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user.rb%20in%3Apath&type=Code&ref=searchresults) `user.rb in:path` do what you want to do? 
Alternatively there is also this [search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filename%3Auser.rb&type=Code&ref=searchresults) `filename:user.rb`

Found on: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/

Comment: using `in:path YOUR_FILENAME_HERE` works great - and super importantly, works cross repo so you can search your entire organizations repos to find which repos contain a certain filename. Nice!

Comment: This is no longer possible. The searches you link return the following error: "We could not perform this search. Must include at least one user, organization, or repository"

Comment: Yes, they do ... you just have to be logged into GitHub for it to work.  Don't know when they changed that. It's a general issue for code search, not just those specific searches.

Comment: It's a pity it only does "path contains this string anywhere" and not like filename globs or anything like that :|

Comment: How to search by extension only?

Comment: My god I wasted a lot of time not realizing that free text search doedsn't include filenames but content only.

Comment: The file name needs to match (without extension), absolute waste of time if you guess a filename. Penny's answer is the better one for that case.

Comment: Unfortunately, [`filename:DEVELOPER.md`](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3ADEVELOPER.md) returns not only `DEVELOPER.md` but `api-documentation-and-developer-portals.md` and `ClientDeveloperDocumentation.md` files as well.
And even [`filename:"DEVELOPER.md"`](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3A%22DEVELOPER.md%22) doesn't help much. _You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] @. The search will simply ignore these symbols._

Comment: This now gives the message "Possible unrecognized qualifier, searching for this term literally"

Answer (score 107):

In search input, you can use `filename` parameter to search in multiple repositories, for example:

```
filename:my_filename.txt
```

If you're looking for a filename in specific repository, you can just press <kbd>t</kbd> and start typing the file name (see: [*GH keyboard shortcuts*](https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/)).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Notice there aren't any spaces in the query.

Comment: it is very funny how searching for **myfile.txt** gives nothing and adding those magic `filename:` prefix makes the search return one file... GitHub, why?! :)

Comment: I tried "filename:" and was suggested by GitHub to use "path:**/your-file-name". Seemed to work with just "path:your-file-name".

Answer (score 35):

GitHub introduced FileFinder in 2011.

> Try it out: just hit t on any repo's file or directory view.[1]

So, You're still restricted to repository.

[1]https://github.com/blog/793-introducing-the-file-finder

Another approach to Your question:

[Can I use Git to search for matching filenames in a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277546/1150918)

**EDIT:** as of 2024 GitHub do seem to provide a way to search for a filename, despite the folder structure of the repository. Please check the "advanced search" section. It do seem to boil down to something like the following:
https://github.com/search?q=path%3A**%2Ftest.c&type=code&ref=advsearch

Or rather `q=path:**/test.c` as it's query argument.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that and should have mentioned it in my question.  So there's no way to search across repositories?  If not, do you know if there is any technical reason why not?

Comment: oh, so You've tried `some_weird_file_Youre_looking_for.ext in:path` too?

Because it [does work](https://github.com/search?q=index.php+in%3Apath&ref=cmdform) for me...

Comment: nope, but I just tried `path:user.rb` and it only gave me 324 results, all which had `user.rb` at the top level.

Comment: And it looks like your results for `index.php` are all at the top level as well.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin yup, it appears to be just on top either... *sigh*

Comment: @Kamiccolo you should post this as an answer, because that's exactly the right answer! Peter Alfvin should accept it as well... the important bit is in:path. Verified that it works no matter where the filename is in the path as well, not just for top-level files.

Comment: Note that once you've entered that mode, the url changes. You can bookmark that changed url, and when you go back to it, you're automatically entered into the "find" mode for searching for a file in a repo/branch. e.g. [for jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/find/main). Combine this with a [custom chrome search engine](https://zapier.com/blog/add-search-engine-to-chrome/) and you can search your target repo super fast for a filename

Comment: Is there a way to permalink to the file finder with the search box pre-populated?  It'd be nice if https://github.com/jquery/jquery/find/main/xyzzy would pre-fill "xyzzy" in the textbox.

Comment: Updated the answer slightly, apparently GitHub currently supports search for particular filename with it's "Advanced Search".

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I wanted to search for a particular file name, in all of my organization's repositories. This can be done by entering this in the search box:

org:*your-organization-user-name* filename:*the-file-name*

Of course, just do "filename:the-file-name" if you want to search the whole of GitHub.

This is now [documented](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories) on Github.

Answer (score 21):

I would like to clarify [@ajain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50860324/6904888)'s answer regarding accessing files in a Github repository via the web UI. Here are the steps:

1. Firstly, you need to be in the [repository's](https://github.com/kaiostech/gecko-b2g) directory view.
   Then, press the <kbd>t</kbd> key. The file finder is now focused.

[image]

[image]

---

---

2. Next, enter the filename of the desired file to open it.

[image]

---

*More shortcuts for **[source code browsing](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts#source-code-browsing)**.*

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation and examples!  This helped me.

Answer (score 10):

You can try Google.  Google for `filename.txt site:github.com`.

Comment: +1 for what I assume matches not only current filenames, but any files which include that text as well as some number of filenames from earlier versions of the repositories.

Comment: what if my GitHub is private or hosted in a company domain.. not gonna work

Comment: tried this and it had no results wheras github advanced search by filename found 3 copies of the modded file i need

Answer (score 7):

I refined @andy-lester [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992315/332890) with `intitle:`, i.e. I want to find where's located the file `simple_spinner_item.xml` in Android's source code hosted on github, so I search on Google this string:

```
site:github.com intitle:simple_spinner_item.xml github.com/android

^                       ^                       ^
|                       |                       |
on github site          |                       |
                        |                       |
filename I'm searching -+                       |
                                                |
github user ------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `path:**/user.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>T</kbd> in the repository's directory view and it will let you search for a file.

Comment: Bit of clarification: you have to already be in the Reop's directory view. See @Kamiccolo's answer below

Answer (score 2):

As of recently, you should simply use `path:user.rb`. This will find files with the name anywhere inside repositories.

Note: The older approaches like `file:user.rb` and `in:path user.rb` seem to not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is:

```
path:<filename>
```

To search for `pyproject.toml` file you would use

```
path:pyproject.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In git Repo Click on "Go to file". It will show "repo/".
2. Enter specific file name.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I followed GH suggestion to add asterisks for a path search:

```bash
path:**/user.rb
```