# On github, how do I search all repos in an org for a filename?

Tags: github

On github, trying to find a file called "test.yaml" in any repos belonging to an org. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991908/is-it-possible-to-search-github-for-a-particular-filename) ?

Comment: Have you seen GitHub Advenced search https://github.com/search/advanced