# Search filenames with regex

Tags: regex, git

Is there any way to do something like `git log <path>`, but instead of path using a regex? I want to search commits containing files, whose filenames match a given pattern...

... and while we're at it: Is there also a way to do a `git status` / `git diff` only for filenames matching a given pattern?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I would be terrific if any way to do it, would also work for Git v1.7.1.

Comment: worth mentioning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277546/can-i-use-git-to-search-for-matching-filenames-in-a-repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple pattern you could try, for example:

```
find . -name "*.c" | xargs git log
```

For a full-blown regex you can use:

```
find . | grep "REGEX" | xargs git log
```

If you need previously deleted files to be included in the output, you can use

```
git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -u | grep "REGEX" | xargs git log --
```

The first part of the above command, which finds all files that were ever in git, was lifted from an answser to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543346/list-all-the-files-that-ever-existed-in-a-git-repository).

Comment: That looks interesting. I give it a try.

Comment: @Nils-o-mat If you have a large directory structure `git ls-files` might be faster than `find .`

Comment: The main downside for me is, that I loose deleted files here. That makes it not a viable option.

Comment: Edited to address deleted files.

Comment: Seems like you were a bit quicker than me. Also we seem to know the same parts of Stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Using `find -iregex 'regex'` is much better than `find | grep 'regex'` -- for one thing, with `-print0` you can feed even extremely weird matches to `xargs -0`.  (For another, saving one process is always good practice, but that's obviously only of marginal importance here.)

Comment: I think the last answer is best, but it will do some strange things on  repositories where the regex matches a lot of files. Also it will choke if the  files have spaces or special characters in their names.

Answer (score 8):

As far as a pure git solution goes and I'm aware of the only option to match specific file patterns is to use a glob.

```
git log -- '*.json'
```

Will give you all files which contain changes to a `json` file. The same can be done for `git status`.

---

On the other hand it's quite easy to search for regular expressions in the diff or the commit message. `git log` offers a `--grep` option to search for matches in the commit message and a `-S` option to search for strings.

[Take a look at this question for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337320/how-to-grep-git-commit-diffs-or-contents-for-a-certain-word).

Comment: The question specifically refers to using a regex, rather than a glob. But if a gob is enough this will work fine.

Comment: I've edited the answer to highlight that I'm speaking about a pure git solution.

Comment: As Michael pointed out a glob is not enough, sorry. Also I have to use git 1.7.1, so the really useful wildcard (**) is not supported...

Comment: @Nils-o-mat then you'll have to take use of other options your shell offers you. A pure git solution won't suffice in that case.

Comment: I got no problem with searching the commit message... That's easy, but filenames are hard...

Comment: @Zeeker I feared that, but thanks a bunch for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers (especially Greg and Michael) I developed a way myself. (I hope this proves viable):

```
git log --name-only --pretty="format:"|sort -u|egrep '<REGEX>'|xargs git log --
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you do something like:

```
git log | grep [string_to_look_for]
```

Comment: How do they filenames come in here? As far as I know git log shows commits?