# While git cloning, Can we know if it does not contain any system files like exe, dll etc?

Tags: git, github

Cloning application from Github, Can we check whether there is system file eg;- .exe, .dll, Looking for the option by which we can restrict the system to clone project which contain such files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use Git to search for matching filenames in a repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277546/can-i-use-git-to-search-for-matching-filenames-in-a-repository)

Comment: `git ls-files *.dll *.exe` will list files that match those patterns in the current repo.

Comment: @Robadob we can do it after git clone right ? not while cloning.

Comment: Try `git ls-remote <repo> *.dll *.exe` before you clone? There wont be a capability to do it during, either do it before or after.

Comment: @Robadob  thanks, I know that, I am looking on while cloning, but if it is not possible then I have to go with other way :(