# how to find specific files in (whole) git repo

Tags: git

How can I find all files (lets say symlinks) ever added to the git repo?

`git ls-tree -r master`

outputs only for one branch and not in the whole history...
(the first column contains the mode, which is `12000` for a link)

I want to search them and then filter them with `git filter-branch`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Git to search for matching filenames in a repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277546/can-i-use-git-to-search-for-matching-filenames-in-a-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running a tree-filter which extracts for each commit all files and checks for the 12000 in the output:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter $'git ls-files --stage | sed -e \'/12000/!d\' --all | cut -f 2'
```

The command does not change files and therefore does not rewrite the history.
I am not sure about this (could somebody assure that?)